# moving Canon pics to Mac OSX files not iPhoto

Tags: macos, folder-redirection

I can't seem to the get the Canon utilities camera window to acknowledge a target folder on my desktop for pictures. It wants to open Aperture and I don't want the pics to go there. I did go into preferences and made a decktop target folder. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to just open the memory card of your camera as a drive and then copy and past the pictures where you want them?

I havnt done this in a while on a mac, but usually when you plug in you camera, it drops a folder on your desktop, where the memory of your camera is mounted as a drive. From there you should just be able to access the pictures directly.

Comment: +agreed... I wouldn't mess with the Canon software, just use finder or the built in add to library stuff in Aperture.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Image Capture](http://www.apple.com/ca/pro/photo/imagecapture.html) instead of the Canon utilities.